# Take percentage form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, math

I have an input field in a rails app where I want percentage. So I'll need:

1. Only numbers (no symbols / periods)
2. The field to always have '%' visible after the input

Form:

```
= form_for @model do |f|
  = f.text_field :price, :maxlength => 3
  = f.submit
```

What is the best way to pull this off? Is there a way I can pull this off in rails or should I use javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I used this plugin to solve it. https://github.com/ruoso/jquery-regex-mask-plugin

To implement it I wrote

```
$('.float').regexMask(/^\d+(,\d+)?$/);
```

super simple.

Answer (score 1):

For item 1 in your question, you should handle this using validations on your model. Something like the following should do it:

```
validates :percentage_field, 
            numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                            greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                            less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
```

For item 2, I would probably put the % sign outside of the input box. Either as part of the prompt or as an element to the right of the input box.

Get that working first with helpful validation messages on the page if the validation fails. If you want to go down the fancy pre-submission javascript messages route, that should be an extra on top of this rather than a solution in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

If you still decided to solve you problem at the JS side you could use native functions like `parseInt` and `parseFloat`. They parse your string values until [the first "invalid" character.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

E.g.

```
parseFloat('10.1%')  -> 10.1
parseInt('10%')      -> 10
parseInt('10.1%')    -> 10
parseFloat('10.1 %') -> 10.1
```